# Readonly false followed by focus is not working in i.e. 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can some one help me..

I have a text box which is readonly by default on page load. On click event of this text box i have to do two things.

- make it editable
- keep focus on text box

For this, i have written a code `removeAttr` to make it editable, then `focus()` to keep focus on it.

It is working in IE8+, FF, Chrome as expected.
But I need to make it work in IE7 too as we have IE7 in client's compatible browsers list.

Note: the problem is only with focus, text box is turned to editable after clicking. But need second click to keep focus in it. Expecting it to be done on the first click only.

```
<input name="testId" id="testId" size="25" maxlength="40"  tabindex="21" class="width250" readonly="true"/>

$("#testId").click(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
   $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Let's see the relevant HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: As @Anthony says, you need to provide the HTML and JavaScript code, otherwise we are simply shooting in the dark. **Edit** your question with code (use [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for instructions on formatting of code within StackOverflow) and then we can try and help you

Comment: So it's readonly until the user clicks, at which point it becomes editable. How is that any different from just being editable in the first place? What is being achieved by having it in the readonly state to begin with?

Comment: @SDC on clicking text box itself, need to make it editable & keep focus on clicked text box. Actual scenario is i have 'n' sections with  2 text boxes in each. when page loaded all sections are disabled and on clicking any of the text box i need to remove readonly attribute of two inputs of that particular section. And focus should be kept on clicked input.

Comment: I still don't get what's being achieved that couldn't be done just by styling them to *look* disabled until they're focussed.

Comment: I have different sections in my page. say 10 sections. Each contains 2 input text boxes. i.e 20 inputs totally. we should allow user to enter input only into either section1 text boxes or section2 text boxes.. and so on. but we should not allow combination. So, be default we made all inputs readonly. when clicking on particular section or input, we just enable input fields of that section & make  readonly true for all other sections inputs.

Comment: Try the following 
`$("#testId").click(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
   $(this).attr('tabindex','0').focus();
});`

Comment: I think some other event may taking the focus out from input element. Add the following code snippet and check.
`jQuery('#testId').focusin(function(){
console.log("focused"); });`

If that is the case then use `e.preventDefault();` after setting the focus.

Comment: focusin event fired the movement when ic licked on readonly textbox, but i don't see focus in text box(i tested by typing some thing). If we think some other event is taking the focus, remaining browsers would also have this problem. But the problem is only with i.e7 not even with i.e8. thanks for your comments Ashwin.

Comment: $("#testId").blur().focus() worked for me.. Thank u all for ur comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the illness of IE is that most of the evens do not update the DOM automatically. What you do is unfocus the element and focus it again to make it editable.

Try this approach it will solve your problem on IE

```
$("#testId").click(function () {
   $(this).removeAttr("readonly").blur().focus();
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! I guess you can accept this answer then. :)

Comment: I have already included your code in my page. how couldn't i accept a great answer that solved my issue?. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a timeout for the `focus`.

```
$("#testId").click(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
   setTimeout(function() {$(this).focus(); }, 10);
});
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600186/focus-doesnt-work-in-ie))

Comment: Tried it. But didn't get my problem solved. Tried with different time intervals 10, 100, 500 & 1000. No use.

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?