# In IE not able to get cursor when focus on input elements of a modal

Tags: html, internet-explorer, types, cursor

I have modal pop-up in which I have few controls like TextArea, Inputs , dropdowns, DatePickers...

When I click on textbox or datepickers, I am not able to see the cursor(but i can see the focus styles applied) in the controls to type something. For the rest it works fine.. If I use tab key or shift+tab from other controls, then even in inputs I am able to see cursor and type..

This issue is only in IE. It works fine in FF and Chrome...

I have no clue what's going on. Please help me with a workaround or solution...

Comment: what happens when you right click, developer mode, and set it to edge?

Comment: I am trying it in edge itself..

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't mean thats what the HTML is running as. It could be set to run in ie8 compatibility

Comment: I knew that its running in Edge. I even double checked by opening developer mode. It shows edge running.......

Answer (score 3):

I recently stumbled upon the same or a very similar problem.

My site had two modal windows. After closing one modal window and then opening the next one, all text inputs on that one were not usable. When I clicked on an input, it changed its state to `focus` (CSS styles showed that) but there was no cursor and I was not able to type anything in. It was however possible to focus it manually using jQuery.

After hours of struggle I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150008/ie-9-and-ie-10-cannot-enter-text-into-input-text-boxes-from-time-to-time) and [this](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9122).

**If an element has focus on it but is removed from the DOM (e.g. closing a modal window), IE is not able to put this focus on other elements.**

This is what helped me:

```
modalWindowDiv.innerHTML = "";
$('#modalWindowDiv').remove();
```

or

```
$('#modalWindowDiv').empty().remove();
```

Just delete the contents of a modal window before removing it from the DOM. That should correctly remove any focus from it.