# Input text field cannot be edited after save - MVC4 - IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have an IE11 specific issue in my web application, after i edit an input text field and save it i cannot edit again the fields in case the cursor was left in one of the text fields, but if i am focusing on something else before i do the save everything works normal.

When the text field is blocked i have to select another element which has an iframe children to make the fields editable.

After the save i load my partial views again to refresh the content of my page.

I have tried to set the focus on the element with the .focus() method after the save but it doesn't work. I have searched for answers and i found two similar issues, but i doesn't seem to solve my problem:

1. [HTML input fields does not get focus when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724749/html-input-fields-does-not-get-focus-when-clicked)
2. [IE 9 and IE 10 cannot enter text into input text boxes from time to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150008/ie-9-and-ie-10-cannot-enter-text-into-input-text-boxes-from-time-to-time)

**Update**:
I figured out that using kendoEditors, after a reload they sometimes become not editable and using the .refresh() this can be fixed, and if i apply the .refresh() in the console everything works fine but if i add to my code as part of the callback function of my reload sometimes it works sometimes not.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried rebooting?

Comment: yes i did, it seems like it is reproducing on different machines as well

Comment: What does the bloked field look like - is it being disabled or readonly, something a css could fix?

Comment: i thought about that, but it works well in Chrome and Firefox, i don't think it is a CSS thing but i will check