# Set focus to dynamically created DIV using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have created

```
Generated code : 

<div id="showInfo_1" style="display: none">
--info 1
</div>

<div id="showInfo_2" style="display: none">
--info 2
</div>

jQuery : $('showInfo_2').focus();
```

This works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

What can I try next?

Comment: You need `$('#showInfo_2').focus();`. Notice the #.

Comment: ^^^ Given the above comment, this should not work currently in any browser.

Comment: sorry typo mistake. yes '#' is added but still is not working in IE 11 but works fine in chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [focus doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600186/focus-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `return false` in the `onclick` and it started working fine the way I expected.

Answer (score 2):

> Attempting to set focus to a hidden element causes an error in
>   Internet Explorer. Take care to only use .focus() on elements that are
>   visible. To run an element's focus event handlers without setting
>   focus to the element, use .triggerHandler( "focus" ) instead of
>   .focus().

from: https://api.jquery.com/focus/