# Angular | Internet Explorer | focus & setting cursor into a input Field

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, input, focus

I implement a small single page in Angular. After opening a second component as a dialog window i need to focus my first input field ( & cursor should at position 1).

Current Situation: i have focus but the cursor isnt inside the field

```
  @ViewChild('gericht') gericht: ElementRef<MatInput>;
  public putInFocus() { this.gericht.nativeElement.focus(); }
```

Browser like chrome or firefox don't have a problem with the method .focus()

Have someone any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE? Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help. With only the above codes, we can't reproduce and locate the issue. Besides, you could try the accepted answer of using `setTimeout` in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600186/focus-doesnt-work-in-ie) to see if it works.

Comment: hi, thank you for u answer. I already tried this solution.

Comment: @YuZhou i have no error

Comment: Could you please give us a reproducible sample? With only the above code, we can't reproduce the issue. You could provide an online code sample using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or any other online code editor.